# Logrotate does not upload to S3

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logrotate

I've spent some hours trying to figure out why logrotate won't successfully upload my logs to S3, so I'm posting my setup here. Here's the thing--logrotate uploads the log file correctly to s3 when I force it like this:

```
sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/haproxy

Starting S3 Log Upload...
WARNING: Module python-magic is not available. Guessing MIME types based on file extensions.
/var/log/haproxy-2014-12-23-044414.gz -> s3://my-haproxy-access-logs/haproxy-2014-12-23-044414.gz  [1 of 1]
 315840 of 315840   100% in    0s     2.23 MB/s  done
```

But it does not succeed as part of the normal logrotate process. The logs are still compressed by my postrotate script, so I know that it is being run. Here is my setup:

/etc/logrotate.d/haproxy =>

```
/var/log/haproxy.log {
    size 1k
    rotate 1
    missingok
    copytruncate
    sharedscripts
    su root root
    create 777 syslog adm
    postrotate
        /usr/local/admintools/upload.sh 2>&1 /var/log/upload_errors
    endscript
}
```

/usr/local/admintools/upload.sh =>

```
echo "Starting S3 Log Upload..."

BUCKET_NAME="my-haproxy-access-logs"

# Perform Rotated Log File Compression                                                                                                        
filename=/var/log/haproxy-$(date +%F-%H%M%S).gz                                                                                              \

tar -czPf "$filename" /var/log/haproxy.log.1

# Upload log file to Amazon S3 bucket                                                                                                         
/usr/bin/s3cmd put "$filename" s3://"$BUCKET_NAME"
```

And here is the output of a dry run of logrotate:

```
sudo logrotate -fd /etc/logrotate.d/haproxy
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/haproxy

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/haproxy.log  forced from command line (1 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/haproxy.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/haproxy.log, log->rotateCount is 1
dateext suffix '-20141223'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/haproxy.log.1 to /var/log/haproxy.log.2 (rotatecount 1, logstart 1, i 1), 
renaming /var/log/haproxy.log.0 to /var/log/haproxy.log.1 (rotatecount 1, logstart 1, i 0), 
copying /var/log/haproxy.log to /var/log/haproxy.log.1
truncating /var/log/haproxy.log
running postrotate script
running script with arg /var/log/haproxy.log : "
        /usr/local/admintools/upload.sh 2>&1 /var/log/upload_errors
"
removing old log /var/log/haproxy.log.2
```

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: What is the file (or dir) `/var/log/upload_errors` for? If it is the log file of `upload.sh`, then the command should be `/usr/local/admintools/upload.sh >> /var/log/upload_errors 2>&1`

Comment: add `set -x` as first line of the `upload.sh` and check the messages

Comment: Yep, that unblocked me. It turned out that my s3cmd was configured for my user, not for root. "ERROR: /root/.s3cfg: No such file or directory
ERROR: Configuration file not available.
ERROR: Consider using --configure parameter to create one." Solution was to copy my config file over.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that when you log in a user ubuntu and try and do `sudo s3cmd --configure` the `.s3cfg` file still gets store in `/home/ubuntu`. Same if you do `sudo bash` first. I'm now manually coying `.s3cfg` to `/root/`, I guess tomorrow we'll know if this works. @worker1138 if you have solved this, consider adding it as answer and marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my s3cmd was configured for my user, not for root.

```
ERROR: /root/.s3cfg: No such file or directory
ERROR: Configuration file not available.
ERROR: Consider using --configure parameter to create one.
```

Solution was to copy my config file over. – worker1138